# if a proc has last step as starting another proc does the first proc wait for the other one to finish before finishing?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, store, database-administration

So I have this proc that does a bunch of delete and inserts and then on the last step it starts another proc on a different server. 
My question is: Does the first proc waits for the second proc to finish ? or it just starts the other proc and done ? 
Because I keep getting sql time out in my vb code and not sure if that could be the reason

Comment: I don't have an answer, but this might be more appropriate for dba.SE. You should also tag which database this is for. A stored proc in SQL Server would probably behave differently than in Mongo, for example.

Comment: try increasing the timeout? is this a deadlock issue? run SQL trace, can you see how far it gets?? tbh, we could do with more detail like maybe some of the VB code.

Comment: dont have access to vb code atm. I did increased time out from 30 seconds - 2 minutes but that didnt help.

Comment: For the time out...I'd guess performance or locking errors.  Do you have access to the SQL code in this case and can you run some monitoring tools on the database?

Comment: its looks like i made a temp fix by running the job that started the first proc less often . instead of running every 2 minutes I tried every 5 minutes and so far haven't got an issue.

Comment: That seems like locking (second run locking the first) to me.  Get runtimes on each proc, your interval can't be faster than the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The first stored procedure will wait for the second stored procedure to execute. This allows you to use the data returned from the second procedure, handle errors, and return an appropriate value.

If you don't want this behaviour, wrap the second stored procedure in a job and trigger the job:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name='RunMyProc'
```

Comment: ohhg I dont need to be like that, Is there a way I can make the first proc finish without waiting for the second one ? because they both on different servers and the first proc lock tables.

Comment: I have added a technique for that.

Comment: But how can i put parameters into a job for the second proc ?

Comment: You would have to script the job to do that, so you could inject the values.

Comment: can you elaborate on this ? and how would I do that ? Do i need to use dynamic sql to create a job with new store proc parameter each time i wanna start it ?